# Poor performance from a Wireless network card

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, drivers

I'm new to Stackexchange, so I apologize if I don't get quite how the platform works yet. Regardless, I believe you're all more than capable of helping me out here.

Currently running Linux (let me know if you need more specific information than that, ie distro or whatnot) and I'm getting really poor performance from a Realtek wireless card that is on my laptop.

Running `sudo lspci` to find out the name of the card lists the following:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SATA Controller (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #4 (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

But really the only thing we should be looking at here is the last "entry" on that list, the one being "`02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)`".

It seems that the wireless network card is the `rtl8188ee` (at least, I *think*  that's the card's name), and I don't know if it's a matter of the driver for this specific card that's built-in to the current Linux kernel being bad or something else.

The ethernet card in this laptop (the `rtl810xE`, judging from the same `lspci` output above) works perfectly fine and I've never had an issue with it, but the Wifi card is a complete other story... hence why I'm asking this public question here. With the wireless network card, I've experienced everything from random connection loss in perfect conditions to outright refusal of networks with all the right requirements.

Has there been noted poor performance from this card in previous versions of the Linux kernel?

And are there any workarounds or other drivers I can use to get better performance out of this card? If so, how would I go about installing those? I only ask this because normally I don't have to work with buggy drivers in Linux since the kernel is built pretty well and so I wouldn't know how to actually do that :sweat_smile: .

Comment: I'm not sure I can help, but I think it's always worth giving as many details as you can about your distro and hardware.

Comment: What is "poor performance", how do you measure it? Downloading stuff half a world away does't measure "performance of WiFi". Does it matter where you are (WiFi performance is *very* sensible to shadowing by walls, ...).